# Alter field collection edit form in hook_menu_alter

Tags: 7

I need to create my own form and validation (when field collection entity is Edited).

```
function common_menu_alter(&$items) {
    //alter add(insert) - working
    $items['field-collection/field-block-id/add/%/%']['page callback'] = '_common_field_collection_item_add';
    //alter edit - not working
    $items['field-collection/field-block-id/%field_collection_item/edit ']['page arguments'] = '_common_field_collection_item_form'
}
```

`_common_field_collection_item_add()` is my own function in my common.module.

I managed to alter the entity on insert, but changing the "edit" part doesn't work. This is the path of my field collection edit: field-collection/field-block-id/%/edit?destination=node/%.
I tried to put this path to `$items`, but it still doesn't not work.

In `hook_form_alter()` I did this.

```
if ($form_id == 'field_collection_item_form' && arg(3) == 'edit') {
       $form['#validate'][] = '_common_field_collection_item_form_validate';
       $form['#submit'][] = '_common_field_collection_item_form_submit';
}
```

Comment: As side note, the code you are showing has two typos: In 'field-collection/field-block-id/%field_collection_item/edit ' there is a space at the end, and in the same line there isn't a semicolon at the end.

Comment: omg you are right, need more coffee thx, this question can be closed now

Comment: A question is not closed because the OP has the answer to his question. If the problem is just that space at the end of the path, then the question can be closed as too localized, though. As it is, it doesn't seem to help future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use the [Field Attach API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/group/field_attach/7) hooks instead.

e.g:

- [hook_field_attach_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_form/7)
- [hook_field_attach_validate](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_validate/7)

Comment: thx but i already found solution :>

Comment: This is the correct way of altering a field form: Using the correct API provided by Drupal.